# Google map **displacement** between two points with given latlong

Tags: java, google-maps

I have two places on google map with some latlong(coordinates), Does there exists any google API to find linear displacement(not road) between them. Or any other library will also do if exists.

Comment: [geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance)

Comment: I want to use it in server side using java. What should I do? Do you have any alternative as your suggestion is in javascript.

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to calculate the points in Java only, you don't need an API. The Haversine formula can do this. Here is the java implementation:

```
public static double distance(double lat1, double lat2, double lng1,
    double lng2) {

final int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth

Double latDistance = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
Double lngDistance = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
Double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)
        + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))
        * Math.sin(lngDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lngDistance / 2);
Double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
double distance = R * c; // convert to meters

return distance;
```

}